# replace json node with another json file with command line jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a `result.json`:

```
{
   "Msg": "This is output",
   "output": {}
}
```

and a `output.json`:

```
{
   "type": "string",
   "value": "result is here"
}
```

I want to replace `output` field in `result.json` with whole file `output.json` as

```
{
   "Msg": "This is output",
   "output": {
       "type": "string",
       "value": "result is here"
   }
}
```

and idea with `jq` command line? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `--argfile` to process multiple files :

```
jq --argfile f1 result.json --argfile f2 output.json -n '$f1 | .output = $f2'
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically the same as Bertrand Martel's answer, but using a different (and shorter) approach to reading the two files.

```
jq -n 'input | .output = input' result.json output.json
```

Comment: great, works as charm, just wonder how can I find some comprehensive tutorial for jq, I googled, but no good luck.

Comment: None that I know of. The man page is good, but could expand on some points. (The streaming stuff is still a complete mystery to me, for example.)